# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax '(14) NOT NULL, `ID_MEMBER` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', `ip` ' at line 3

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

Im getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL, 
`ID_MEMBER` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', `ip` ' at line 3
```

When I run this script:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MVElog_online` (
  `session` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '0',
  `logTime` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  `ID_MEMBER` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `url` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`session`),
  KEY `logTime` (`logTime`),
  KEY `ID_MEMBER` (`ID_MEMBER`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

What does the error mean and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the error closely, it is telling you exactly where the problem is: `timestamp(14)` is a syntax error meaning you are putting things together that don't belong.  It is telling you to read the manual on how to write an SQL query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timestamp` should not have length, (It's `timestamp` not `timestamp(14)`)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MVElog_online` (
  `session` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '0',
  `logTime` timestamp NOT NULL,                 -- HERE
  `ID_MEMBER` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `url` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`session`),
  KEY `logTime` (`logTime`),
  KEY `ID_MEMBER` (`ID_MEMBER`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: Yes!! I just noticed it! Thank you!

Comment: [MySQL DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)